# Are there any covid-19 vaccine side effects that can't be gained from a covid infection?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, vaccine

Some side effects from a covid vaccine are caused by the patient's immune system's response to the vaccine - for example myocarditis ([source 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7199677/), [source 2](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36045681/#:%7E:text=Importantly%2C%20genes%20involved%20in%20neutrophil,vaccination%2C%20even%20with%20antipyretic%20drugs.)) - which will therefore also occur from a covid infection.

Is this true for all covid-19 vaccine (specifically Moderna and Pfizer) side effects, or are there some side effects that can only caused by the vaccine and not from a covid infection?

Edit: for clarification, this question refers to all components of the vaccine (including adjuvants)

Comment: I assume you mean from the antigen producing bit in the vaccine, not the components used as adjuvants and (in the case of Moderna and Pfizer) for transfection of the host cells?

Comment: @bob1 I don't see a need or reason to make that assumption.

Comment: @bob1 I didn't consider adjuvants, I'll add that to my list of things to research. For this question let's refer to all components of the vaccine (including adjuvants)

Comment: A sore arm and allergic reactions. Despite more than 12 billion doses of mRNA vaccines administered worldwide, I can't find any adverse events reported unique to the vaccines other than those two. I would write an answer but the effort doesn't seem worth it. There's just too much data to summarize.

Comment: @CareyGregory thank you and no worries, that lines up with my research too.